# Keeping track of the amount of times a user inputs a number

Tags: javascript

Im rettively new to JavaScript and im trying to figure out how to keep track of the integers a user inputs on a field. Ideally the user's would be able to input a value in a field and depending on the range of the number the counter would increase for any of the three options. Id like to display the total number for of the three groups on the output. What I have below is not letting me do this. Any advice is appreciated.

```
function printOutAges(){
       
   var sAge =  document.getElementById("participatntAge").value;
   var groupPlacement = "";
   var juniorCounter = 0 ;
   var intermediateCounter = 0;
   var seniorCounter = 0;    
   
   
   if (sAge >= 4 && sAge <= 7){
       juniorCounter ++;
   }
   else if (sAge >= 8 && sAge <= 11){
    intermediateCounter ++;
   }
   else if (sAge >= 12 && sAge <= 15){
    
    seniorCounter ++;
   }

   

   document.getElementById("recievedInfo").innerHTML = "The amount of juniors are " + juniorCounter + '<br>' + "Intermediate is " + intermediateCounter + '<br>' +"  Senior is " + seniorCounter;
}
```

Below is the HTML

```
<!DocType html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Soccer </title>
</head>    
<body>

    <h1>  league registration!</h1>
    

    <script src="week5.js"></script>

    <form> 
        <input type="number" id="participatntAge" placeholder="Age">
        <p id = "recievedInfo"></p>
    </form>
      
    <button onclick="printOutAges()"> submit </button>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and use the guidance to edit your question to be clear about the issue

Comment: Can you show us the HTML and the javascript launchinh this JS functions?

Comment: I don't get this part.
getAges(juniorCounter);
What is it for?

Comment: @FlorentCardot Updated with the HTML

Comment: @Nikita that was for something else I was trying that was left over

Answer (score 1):

Every time you will click on the submit button, you will reset all 3 counters.
You must declare counters outside of your function otherwise they will be reset.

```
    <!DocType html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title> Soccer </title>
    </head>    
    <body>
    
        <h1>  league registration!</h1>
        
    
        <script src="week5.js"></script>
    
        <form> 
            <input type="number" id="participatntAge" placeholder="Age">
            <p id = "recievedInfo"></p>
        </form>
          
        <button onclick="printOutAges()"> submit </button>
    
    </body>
    <script>
           var juniorCounter = 0 ;
           var intermediateCounter = 0;
           var seniorCounter = 0; 
        function printOutAges(){
           // Contains your age
           var sAge =  document.getElementById("participatntAge").value;
           // unused
           var groupPlacement = "";

           //var juniorCounter = 0 ;
           //var intermediateCounter = 0;
           //var seniorCounter = 0; 
   if (sAge >= 4 && sAge <= 7){
       juniorCounter ++;
   }
   else if (sAge >= 8 && sAge <= 11){
    intermediateCounter ++;
   }
   else if (sAge >= 12 && sAge <= 15){
    seniorCounter ++;
   }
   document.getElementById("recievedInfo").innerHTML = "The amount of juniors are " + juniorCounter + '<br>' + "Intermediate is " + intermediateCounter + '<br>' +"  Senior is " + seniorCounter;
}
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: Alright, thanks! This seems to have worked

Comment: If this solved your problem, please flag it as solved